# How to resolve "Ensure SQL Server Browser is running" , when it is

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2017-express

I'm creating an Android App using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2017.  Since this includes storing data, I'm using SQL Server 2017 to accomplish this.  When I run my code, and debug the line "conn.Open()", I get an error stating that I should ensure that SQL Server Browser is running.  However, when I check SQL Configuration Manager, it is running.

Some things I've tried
- Making sure that the connection string in SQL Server matches the connection string in my code
- I've tried changing what the SQL Server Browser is logged into (Whether it's local system, local service, etc.)
- I've tried several different methods of implementing an insert statement in my code

```
    public class ConnectionManager
    {
        public static SqlConnection NewCon;
        public static string ConStr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-V83O00S\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ResourceSharing;Integrated Security=True";

        public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            NewCon = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            return NewCon;
        }

    }



    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                            SqlConnection conn;
            conn = ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
            conn.Open();
            string cmdString = "INSERT into Login values(@username,@password)";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdString, conn);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "josh123";
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "pwd321";
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();


    }
```

Expected Result:  1 record in my Login table

Actual Result: Error asking me to ensure SQL Server Browser is running.

Any feedback or suggestions on either how to fix this problem or what alternative route I can take that would work?

Comment: You shouldn't connect to database servers directly from mobile-device applications because your app will be suspended or resumed without warning at any point, and database connection protocols (like SQL Server's TDS) are stateful, with expensive set-up and tear-down logic. This is why mobile-apps almost always communicate with a database via an intermediate web-server because HTTP is stateless.

Comment: Anyway - your computer's firewall is probably blocking all external SQL Server connections. Also, by default, SQL Server Express (which you're using) is not configured to respond to TCP connections, only Local connections using Named Pipes or Shared Memory.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the feedback.  Do you have a suggested method for storing data for retrieval later?  My end goal is to create my own app (I have an android phone, so either android-based or cross-platform), and put it in the app store.

Comment: @Dai I know you said a web service, but what web service would be good?

Comment: Write your own webService by using c#,java and etc. Read the official document to find which one is right for you.